# JavaScript: GET value from popup (external website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using this code to get a value from a field in popup.

http://myotherwebsitename.com/parent.html

```
<input type="text" id="output"/>
<button id="show">Open</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function(){
        window['output'] = document.getElementById('output');
        window.open('http://mywebsite.com/map.html')
    });
</script>
```

http://mywebsite.com/map.html

```
<input type="text" id="user_text"/>
<input id="send" type='button' value'send'/>

<script>
    document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.opener['output'].value = document.getElementById('user_text').value;
})
</script>
```

It works well if both are hosted on the same website, but if i put one of these on other website it doesn't work.

How can i make it working for different websites?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. The same-origin policy prohibits you from accessing the contents of other web sites.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Due to same origin policy you can't get info from another website.  here is a better definition of why...

In computing, the same-origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port number[1] – to access each other's DOM with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to DOM on different sites.[1] Same-origin policy also applies to XMLHttpRequest and to robots.txt.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.

hope this helps.  I'll see if I can find a workaround and let you know though.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, same origin policy...

If you have access to external site, you can grant access to your first domain by setting **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header on request OPTIONS. Here PHP example:

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $allowedList))
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
        exit;
    }
```

But you should known, that HTTP_ORIGIN contains schema, and you should specify both http and https domains in $allowedList.

Comment: Yes, I have access to external site, it's mine.

Comment: Than you should check server access logs, maybe OPTIONS denied by server configuration and so on