# Ajax POST keep firing error function event though php script success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am using jquery, jquery mobile and html to build a mobile app using phonegap.

Using ajax to call php scripts in server, works fine; updating, inserting data and sending email. However ajax error function is what always called, 
Using firebug, 200 ok status is what returned, no idea what triggers error.

I have searched for this issues and found many suggestions here such as using complete () or done() functions instead of success() and error(), echoing json response... but no luck with all these solutions.

one solution is to add  this header to php script,

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

header solution has solved my problem with all ajax post scripts, however I am concerning about possible security risks because it is should run in mobile application.

In addition, adding such header can be logic when we need to access database but if we have a contact form that call php mail function and no database changes will occur , why we need to add that header too?

contact form

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
<input type="button" value="Send" name="sendbutton"  id="sendbtn"   />
 <h1>contact us</h1>
<a data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext"></a>       
</div>

<div data-role="content" >    
<form id="contact-us" >
<input type="text"  id="contactName"  placeholder="Name" />
<input type="email"  id="email"  placeholder="Your Email" />
<input type="text"  id="subject"  placeholder="Message Subject" />
<textarea rows="20" cols="30" id="message"  placeholder="Message.." ></textarea>
</form>         
</div>
```

Jquery script

```
       $("#sendbtn").click(function(event){
            $("#sendbtn").disabled =true;
            var postData ="";

            if($("#contactName").val().length == 0 ||$("#email").val().length == 0 ||$("#subject").val().length == 0||$("#message").val().length == 0)
                alert("Sorry but some required fields are empty !");
            else {
                if (!regex.test($("#email").val()))
                    alert("Please check that you write email correctly!");   
                else {
                    postData='contactName=' + $("#contactName").val() + '&email=' + $("#email").val() + '&subject=' + $("#subject").val() + '&message=' + $("#message").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: postData,
                        url: 'mydomainname.net/services/contact.php',
                        success: function(){

                            $('input').not('[type="button"]').val('');
                            $('textarea').val(''); 
                            alert('Message was Sent, Thank you!');
                        }, 
                        error:  function () {
                            alert('Sorry, Error  occurred ');
                            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
                    }


                    });  
 }
}
 });
```

php code

```
<?php

 if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['contactName']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
      foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
        if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
          exit;
        }
      }    
      mail( "myemail@mydomainname.net", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['contactName']." Title ".$_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], "From:" . $_POST['email']);
      }
      ?>
```

The code send email but always called ajax error function

Any other solution rather than header solution? thank you.

Comment: You're missing some close braces in the Javascript.

Comment: What error do you see in the Network tab in the Developer Tools?

Comment: Is the AJAX server in the same domain as the client script? Then leave the domain out of the URL.

Comment: You are right but this is just a part of the code :) thank you.

Comment: It could be the lack of a response from the server, try echoing something from your PHP script

Comment: @Barmar No, client script is supposed to be in the mobile app.

Comment: @Rob M even with echoing msg or json,  error function always fired :S

Comment: @Barmar the Network tab show at first 407 then 200

Answer (score 0):

there some unclose breaks, try this :

```
$("#sendbtn").click(function(event){
    $("#sendbtn").disabled =true;
    var postData ="";


    if($("#contactName").val().length == 0 ||$("#email").val().length == 0 ||$("#subject").val().length == 0||$("#message").val().length == 0) {
        alert("Sorry but some required fields are empty !");
    } else {
        if (!regex.test($("#email").val())) {
            alert("Please check that you write email correctly!");  
        } else {
            postData='contactName=' + $("#contactName").val() + '&email=' + $("#email").val() + '&subject=' + $("#subject").val() + '&message=' + $("#message").val();
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        url: 'contact.php',
        success: function(){

        $('input').not('[type="button"]').val('');
        $('textarea').val(''); 
            alert('Message was Sent, Thank you!');
        }, 
        error:  function ()
        {
            alert('Sorry, Error  occurred ');
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i think, collecting postData you should do like `$('#my-form').serialize();`

> url: 'mydomainname.net/services/contact.php'

url should be set with scheme prefix, if you want post to another server.

> however I am concerning about possible security risks.

At server side you can check domain and than decide - send allowed header or not.

Comment: Thanks How to check the domain if I want the script to accept calls from mobile app?  For .serialize(); u r right but it dosen't work with me, don't know why

Comment: I already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20260062/2281537, please view it.

Comment: Thank you it is very useful if it was another domain requesting, adding it to the allowedList, but if the case was a mobile app that cross domain to load & post data, how to secure this?

Comment: If your mobile app are doing some requests to server, it's not a cross domain. Because, your requests are direct requests to your server. You should check server's accessibility for "X-Requested-With" (ajax requests) headers, maybe they are denied by server configuration.